# openerp create database error

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am getting following error while creating a new database in openerp.
kindly suggest how to proceed?

OpenERP WebClient Error

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131226-002345\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131226-002345\Server\server\openerp\addons\auth_signup\controllers\main.py", line 39, in get_config
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131226-002345\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_config_parameter.py", line 74, in get_param
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131226-002345\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 2369, in search
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131226-002345\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 4887, in _search
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131226-002345\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20131226-002345\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
ProgrammingError: relation "ir_config_parameter" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "ir_config_parameter".id FROM "ir_config_parameter" W...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved, i have removed all custom add-ons this resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if your Openerp addons directory has any module module which has quite a large name. You can again try to create a new database with extra modules included. You will get the same error. Hope you are not making a module name too long :)